# Get First 6 elements from the array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the first 6 elements from my array. I am using an API `'themoviedb'`.

I am fetching the data from the API and storing the data in an array.

```
var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=YOURKEY&language=en-US&page=1";
var img  = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
var tvSeriesImg = [];

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();     // New instance of XMLHttpRequest
request.open('GET', url, true);         // Open the connection using the 'GET' Method
request.onload = function(){          // Create an onload function this is where the data is displayed on the webpage

var data = JSON.parse(this.response);    // Creating a data variable where our JSON is parsed and stored.

if(request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){      // Check the request status.

    data.results.forEach(results => {                   //Looping through the JSON Array

        const popTvSeries = document.getElementById('tv-series-data');
        const popTvSeriesCard = document.createElement('div');
        popTvSeriesCard.setAttribute('id', 'card');
        popTvSeries.appendChild(popTvSeriesCard);

        tvSeriesImg.push(results.poster_path);

        //Get the first 6 items from the array!!
        console.log(tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6));
        const tvImage = document.createElement('img');
        tvImage.src = img + tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6);
        tvImage.setAttribute('id', 'movieThumb');
        popTvSeriesCard.appendChild(tvImage);
    });
}

}

request.send();
```

I have tried using the slice method however I am getting the following error:

https://ibb.co/T1S8RqX

Comment: Have you tried to use a for looo where your index i starts at 0 up to 5?

Comment: The error you get is a 404 HTTP error, which has nothing to do with slicing the response.

Comment: why are you adding an array to src?

Comment: Please don't link to an external site.  If you are posting an error message, post the **text** of the error here, in your question.  I'm not going to click on the "ibb" link.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error is from this:

```
// you're setting the src of the image as 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/val1/val2/val3/val4/val5/val6' which doesn't make sense
tvImage.src = img + tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6);
```

Try replacing this block:

```
console.log(tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6));


        const tvImage = document.createElement('img');
        tvImage.src = img + tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6);
        tvImage.setAttribute('id', 'movieThumb');
        popTvSeriesCard.appendChild(tvImage);
```

with this:

```
tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6).map((imgUrl) => {
    const tvImage = document.createElement('img');

    // set src = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/valx" where '/valx' is the imgUrl.
    tvImage.src = img + imgUrl;
    tvImage.setAttribute('id', 'movieThumb');
    popTvSeriesCard.appendChild(tvImage);
})
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified forEach that will fix your issue.

```
const cards = document.getElementById('tv-series-data')

results.forEach(result => {

  const card = document.createElement('div')
  card.id = result.id // ID's should be unique

  card.innerHTML = `<img src="${img}${result.poster_path}">`
  cards.appendChild(card)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is very confusing, without being able to see the site where you are running and testing the code. However, I think your issue is with the second half:

```js
//Get the first 6 items from the array!!
        
        tvSeriesImg.push(results.poster_path);

        console.log(tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6));


        const tvImage = document.createElement('img');
        tvImage.src = img + tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6);
        tvImage.setAttribute('id', 'movieThumb');
        popTvSeriesCard.appendChild(tvImage);
```

You are storing the paths in an array and then in the console log printing out the first 6 every time it adds one even if there isn't 6. Which is a little confusing but assuming this is code. Then you are doing

```js
 tvImage.src = img + tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6);
```

This will remove the first 6 elements from the array, every time it loops and appends it to the img URL, so you are trying to add as a src a URL that is an array of 6 elements. hence the error. the url is becoming something like  http://img.com/absec.jpg,abb.jpg, etc...

Since I can't test it as I don't have an API key there maybe an error but your code should look like:

```js
var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=f1d314280284e94ff7d1feeed7d44fdf&language=en-US&page=1";
var img = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
var tvSeriesImg = [];

var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // New instance of XMLHttpRequest
request.open('GET', url, true); // Open the connection using the 'GET' Method
request.onload = function() { // Create an onload function this is where the data is displayed on the webpage

  var data = JSON.parse(this.response); // Creating a data variable where our JSON is parsed and stored.

  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) { // Check the request status.


    data.results.forEach(results => { //Looping through the JSON Array

      const popTvSeries = document.getElementById('tv-series-data');

      const popTvSeriesCard = document.createElement('div');
      popTvSeriesCard.setAttribute('id', 'card');
      popTvSeries.appendChild(popTvSeriesCard);

      tvSeriesImg.push(results.poster_path);

    });
    //remove from loop since you only want the top 6
    const tvImage = document.createElement('img');
    var first6Urls = tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6);
    for (var i = 0; i < first6Urls.length; i++) {
      tvImage.src = img + first6Urls[i]
      tvImage.setAttribute('id', 'movieThumb' + i+1);
      popTvSeriesCard.appendChild(tvImage);
    }
  }
}
request.send();
```

Basically, you need to put the extraction and appending code outside of your for each loop and append them one by one.

Answer (score -1):

You must create a child img for each tvSeriesImg value:

```
var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/popular?api_key=YOURKEY&language=en-US&page=1";
var img  = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
var tvSeriesImg = [];

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();     // New instance of XMLHttpRequest
request.open('GET', url, true);         // Open the connection using the 'GET' Method
request.onload = function(){          // Create an onload function this is where the data is displayed on the webpage

var data = JSON.parse(this.response);    // Creating a data variable where our JSON is parsed and stored.

if(request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400){      // Check the request status.
    data.results.forEach(results => {                   //Looping through the JSON Array
        const popTvSeries = document.getElementById('tv-series-data');
        const popTvSeriesCard = document.createElement('div');
        popTvSeriesCard.setAttribute('id', 'card');
        popTvSeries.appendChild(popTvSeriesCard);

        tvSeriesImg.push(results.poster_path);

        //Get the first 6 items from the array!!
        console.log(tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6));

        tvSeriesImg.slice(0, 6).forEach(x => {
            const tvImage = document.createElement('img');
            tvImage.src = img + x;
            tvImage.setAttribute('id', 'movieThumb');
            popTvSeriesCard.appendChild(tvImage);
        });
    });
}
}

request.send();
```